# Can I connect multiple different devices via a single I2S interface?

Tags: microphone, i2s, digital-audio, audio-codec

I am using a microcontroller with only one I2S interface. I am using MAX98357A which has 1 sound chip. There is 1 microphone, SPH0645. Can I connect these ICs to the same line provided that I cannot use them at the same time? Can I then communicate with each of them separately with I2S like below figure?

[image]

Comment: We don't know without further info. First of all, which exact MCU that is, and does it have only one data line for input or output, or two data lines for input and output?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521936/i2s-between-multiple-devices?rq=1

Comment: @Hari A blanket statement of "no" may not apply here. Some MCUs have I2S interfaces for codecs which means they can receive and transmit simultaneously.

Comment: I am using ESP32WROOM32-E. I know It has two I2S port but other pins are used as different purposes. So, I have only one port. @Justme

Comment: @FAFİ Yes so how many data pins and into which directions that single I2S port has?

Comment: @Justme I couldnt understand. I know that the I2S pins are configured by software. I shared related link below.

[esp32-i2s-link](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2s.html)